# jQuery removeClass() method not firing within For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my jQuery code changes my select-option elements into divs. When each `.lev0` div is clicked on, a hidden div of class `.BGbord2` will show, and class `.opened2` will be appended to `.BGbord2`. My problem is that once appended, `removeClass("opened2")` will not work.

So the result I want achieved is this: when div `data-level="SUB1-1"` is clicked on, then div of `id="SUB1-1"` shows. And when div `data-level="SUB2-1"` is clicked on, then div of `id="SUB2-1"` shows and hides div of `id="SUB1-1"`. The current code I have is unable to do that. As you can see from my jQuery code on the 3rd line from the bottom, I've commented above the code which is not working,

the - `$(this).parents(".BGbord").siblings('#'+SUBdiv).removeClass("opened2");`

I don't know how to get this to work. I've added my code snippet here to make things easier. Please help me

Comment: Please clarify, the commented out line is supposed to remove the class that was just added to the exact same element the line before? The selectors are identical.

Comment: Yes, the commented out lines removes the element, and the line before adds it. I'm trying to get the `removeClass("opened2")` to remove, but it can't basically.

Comment: I'm sorry to be obtuse, but why add and immediately remove the class name? That doesn't really make any sense. Just don't add it in the first place.

Comment: So.. then how do I remove the element if I "just don't add it"?

Comment: Just to be really very clear, the commented out line doesn't _remove the element_. It is attempting to remove a class name from the element. A class name that is added to the very same element the line before. How is this not clear to you? Look at the code and you can read `blah.blah.addClass("opened2")` immediately followed by exactly the same code except `removeClass("opened2")`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Honestly, I didn't think the code made sense either. I basically borrowed and edited some of this code. The reason I subsequently used the add/removeClass is because I assumed it would work, judging by how add/removeClass() worked on the `.lev0` click function 11 lines above that. I'm confused how these methods work on the `.lev0` element but not on the `data-level` element

Comment: I've explained in my answer. Please let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've overcomplicated something that is very simple to accomplish.

Please look at this sample that demonstrate what you are attempting without the complexity of creating components for now.

Please let me know what questions you have:

```js
const subMenus = document.querySelectorAll('menu[data-parent]');
document.querySelector('#menu-container').addEventListener('click', showSub);

function showSub(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName !== 'MENU') return;
  subMenus.forEach(el => {
    el.style.visibility = "hidden"
  });
  document.querySelector(`menu[data-parent="${e.target.id}"]`).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
menu {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 2px;
}


menu li {
  margin: 3px;
}

menu li:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

menu[data-parent] {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="menu-container">
  <menu id="menu-one">Menu One
    <menu data-parent="menu-one">
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
    </menu>
  </menu>
  <menu id="menu-two">Menu Two
    <menu data-parent="menu-two">
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
    </menu>
  </menu>
</section>
```

Comment: I am still so confused. I'm tried your method but it's not working. So you're saying I just change the `(".BGbord")` part to `(".BGbord2")` and place it underneath the click function for `data-level="SUB'+i+'-1` right?

Comment: Also, I see there's also something else wrong with my script. The `data-level="SUB'+i+'-1` divs underneath `BGbord` contain the exact same attribute&value combination for the child divs underneath the `BGbord2` and I feel like this might be what's confusing both the CSS and jQuery targeting.

Comment: So I removed the identical `data-level` attribute/value combination for the divs within `BGbord2` and still get the same result :/

Comment: Please see the "new" answer. If you don't find this helpful I'll delete it.

Comment: Wow, you rewrote a whole working code! I'm still trying to study this and get it to work with the current one I have, so sorry if it seems like I'm taking long to respond. I'm still a beginner with jquery/javascript. But I really appreciate you taking the time to explain and set examples. These are so very helpful. I will comment back once I have questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - took over a day but this helped me to solve my code - Marking as best answer!